# Код поиска с переходом по url

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5, redirect

нужен код, который будет из поиска переходить по ссылке с заданными символами. Например: Ввожу в поиске 1234, и переходит по ссылке сайт.ру/1234
Нашел что-то похожее, но не получается расчистить `"?text="`

```
<form action="https://сайт.ру/" target="_blank"> 
  <input type="search" name="text"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Найти"> 
</form>
```

Если убираю "text", то ломается и не отображается вводимое при переходе, а так переходит при вводе "1234" на сайт.ру/?text=1234. А нужно, чтобы переходило на сайт.ру/1234

Answer (score 2):

Можно такой вариант использовать. Вообще, много вариантов есть.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', ev => {
  document.querySelector('.link').setAttribute('href', `https://site.com/${ev.target.value}`)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" value="">
<a href="#" class="link">Search</a>
```

Comment: Благодарю, но ничего не вышло.. пробовал разными путями использовать код, который выше, но так и не выводится с чистым вывода url. Может быть, у вас есть еще какой-то вариант, самый элементарный, поделитесь пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: @Bob Этот вариант, мне казалось, итак максимально прост... Покажите как вы его прописывали у себя, поправлю.

Answer (score 1):

можно и такое использовать!

```js
function search() {
  window.location = 'https://site.ru/search/' + document.querySelector('.search').value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search">
<button onclick="search()">Поиск</button>
```

**может здесь не работать потому-что на StackOverflow запрещено выходить на другие ссылки, просто скопируйте это на ваш код и всё будет работать**

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]